# Angular 4 Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export interface IComments{
    comments: string;
}

export interface IReport {
   reportdesc: string;
   comnts: [IComments]
}

export interface IRecord{
   rdesc: string;
   reportcomments: [IReport]
}

In template I get a single value of IRecord using comment  
<div>
<input [(ngModel)]="record.rdesc" name="rdesc">
<table>
<thead *ngFor="let d of record.reportcomments">
   <tr>
     <td>{{d.reportdesc}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let a of d.comnts">
    <td>{{a.comments}}</td>
   </tr>  
</thead>
</table>
```

In component I am trying to push an empty row like this

```
record=IRecord[]=[];

addRow(){
   this.record.reportcomments.push({
    rdes:'',
    comnts: {
         comments: ''
});
```

when I call addRow() from template to push the empty row i get error

```
Error: TypeError: cannot read property 'push' if undefined.
```

Please let me know how to fix my approach so I can add empty row. 
I already checked the previous similar questions without any luck.
Thank

Comment: you trying to create and array of arrays and you are trying to push a single array , you need to push an array instead of a object

Comment: can you give me example of what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

```
record=IRecord[]=[];
record.reportcomments = [];

addRow(){
   this.record.reportcomments.push({
    rdes:'',
    comnts: {
         comments: ''}
});
```

Defining the reportcomments as empty array wont give you error as `reportcomments` is `undefined`

```
record.reportcomments = [];
```

and one more thing there is missing closing brace for comments which i believe you forget to add while copy pasting the code, please check this line `comments: ''}`

Comment: when i try record.reportcomments=[]; i get error duplicate identifier record

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the variable correctly like following:

```
let reports: [IReport] = [{}];
let record:IRecord = {rdesc: "My Report", reportcomments:reports};
```

The model should define all nullable fields should be declared with ? like following:

```
export interface IComments{
comments: string;
}

export interface IReport {
reportdesc?: string;
comnts?: [IComments]
}

export interface IRecord{
rdesc?: string;
reportcomments?: [IReport]
}
```